# How to fix this error in the following codes?

Tags: dart

Could someone tell me how to fix this please?

This is in the main.dart error line.

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFlDp.png

Another file's code, I think this might related to the error.

````
List<CovidTodayResult> covidTodayResultFromJson(String str) => List<CovidTodayResult>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => CovidTodayResult.fromJson(x)));

String covidTodayResultToJson(List<CovidTodayResult> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));  ```
````

Comment: The error is explicit really. Your function expected type is return type is a future of CovidTodayResult but the result variable is of type List<CovidTodayResult>. If we can see the function clearly we would know how to help.

Answer (score 0):

As your image states, you're declaring the return type as `Future<CovidTodayResult>`, but you're not returning a `Future`. If you want this specific code to work you should change your return type to `List<CovidTodayResult>` or if you're using `await` in your method, which I can't see, `Future<List<CovidTodayResult>>`.